# How can I use polymorphism in Spring Boot Services?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am currently working on a Spring Boot project and I would like to speed up process of writing the service/data layer boilerplate code (one service and one repository (`CrudRepository`) for every entity, every one having mostly the same methods).

As of now I am using `TABLE_PER_CLASS` inheritance in several entities (e.g.: `Warehouse` and `Office` are subclasses of `Location` (an abstract class defining common attributes for all locations).

I would like to define 1 repository and 1 service to manage both `Location` and its subtypes so I can do something like in my control layer:

```java
@Autowired
LocationsService locationsService;

Warehouse cityWarehouse = new Warehouse();
Office centralOffice = new Office();

locationsService.addNewLocation(cityWarehouse);
locationsService.addNewLocation(centralOffice);
```

I know I can just use method overloading but I would really like to avoid repeating the same code in situations like this one.

I've also tried using parametric polymorphism:

```java
@Service
public class LocationsService {

    @Autowired
    LocationsRepository locationsRepository;

    public void addNewLocation(Location location) {
        locationsRepository.save(location);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this won't work as Spring can't tell if I want to save a `Location` or a `Warehouse` object:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: 
Unable to find com.test.springboot.entities.locations.Location with id 55db6993-8a58-4e3a-a6ab-d60d93ab6182; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.test.springboot.entities.locations.Location with id 55db6993-8a58-4e3a-a6ab-d60d93ab6182
```

I need to use concrete `Location` objects so using `@MappedSuperclass` is not an option.

Is there something I am missing? Is it even posible to achieve what I want?

Please note that I am fairly new to Spring Boot so maybe there's something obvious I don't know about yet.

Comment: uhm, afaik, you can use `@MappedSuperclass` with concrete classes, however, I would like to know why you need to do this, because I don't see the actual usage of this

Comment: you're right, but then I won't be able to persist those classes (because they are not entities anymore)

Comment: yes but the problem with this is the other way around... how will hibernate be able to know (when you retrieve data) which entity you are referring to? If you can add a column, you can use `@DiscriminatorColumn` to solve this

Comment: oh, so I can define my service layer methods using parametric polymorphism and then, adding the `@DiscriminatorColumn` to each subclass, hibernate will know which entity I want to persist?

Comment: yes, check https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance 3.1+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working thanks to some of the comments and after briefly reading the JPA specification.

Because I wanted to use my superclasses as entities I ended up using `SINGLE_TABLE` inheritance.

For example, this is the `Location` entity:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "location_type")
public class Location {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    // Skipped 

}
```

The key here is to use `@DiscriminatorColumn` with `SINGLE_TABLE` inheritance in the parent class and add `@DiscriminatorValue` in the correspondent subclasses:

```java
@Entity
@Data @Accessors(chain = true)
@DiscriminatorValue("warehouse_location")
public class Warehouse extends Location {

    @JoinColumn(name = "INTERNAL_ROUTE_ID")
    @OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true)
    private Route internalRoute;

    @JoinColumn(name = "EXTERNAL_WAREHOUSE_ID")
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Warehouse> externalWarehouses;
}
```

This way, I can define `LocationsRepository` as:

```java
public interface LocationsRepository extends CrudRepository<Location, Long> {
    Warehouse findByCityIgnoreCase(String city);
}
```

Also note that subclass-specific methods can be defined here as long as its return type is explicitly specified (otherwise the method would return ALL Locations, not just the Warehouses).

Finally, in the service layer I can make the relevant methods return any entity just by downcasting the result of the repository call into the appropriate subclass